# Mobile Web Applications for Android and IOS, Remote Debugging, Emulators, Simulators?

Tags: remote-debugging

I am developing a mobile web app targeting Android, IOS, BB.

In order to be able to do remote debugging I have found Adobe Edge Inspect, Google Developer Tools, Web Inspector on Safari,

Is there a better way of doing remote inspection?

Thanks

Comment: Turned out these are the best options.

Answer (score -1):

I found [WEINRE](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) really helpful.

weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.
If you aren't familiar with FireBug or Web Inspector, weinre isn't going to make too much sense to you. weinre reuses the user interface code from the Web Inspector project at WebKit, so if you've used Safari's Web Inspector or Chrome's Developer Tools, weinre will be very familiar. If you're not familiar with Web Inspector, the links above to Google's and Apple's documentation will be useful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.